# Error resolving template, template might not exists or might not be accessible by any of the configuration

Tags: spring-boot, thymeleaf

I am using a Thymeleaf template in my main Spring boot controller.

I have now tried to create the following test controller:

```
@Controller
public class TestController{

    @GetMapping("/test")
    public String testController(HttpServletRequest request) {
        System.out.println(request);

        return "hi";
    }

}
```

and I keep getting the error:

```
org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateInputException: Error resolving template [Hello], template might not exist or might not be accessible by any of the configured Template Resolvers
```

Could someone explain to me why I'm getting this error and I can't just return "hi" to the get Request?

Answer (score 2):

Adding @ResponseBody annotation as follows fixes the issue:

```
@Controller
public class TestController{

    @GetMapping("/test")
    @ResponseBody
    public String testController(HttpServletRequest request) {
        System.out.println(request);

        return "hi";
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

The above assumes you have a hi.html file located in PROJECTBASE/src/main/resources/templates